# Why doesn't my tub faucet shut off completely?

Tags: water, bathtub, leaking, spout

The handle of the shower has been in the off position all day. No one has showered here and yet there is water dripping from the bottom tub spout. We took it off and found water still dripping from the pipe itself.

[image]

Comment: It was leaking from the spout so I thought the spout needed replacement but it was actually the pipe, not the spout. Thank you for your responses, I will consult a plumber.

Comment: It's not the _pipe_, either. Pipes don't control water flow any more than spouts do. See that handle up there? ...

Answer (score 1):

You're doing OK. Before you consult a plumber, I'd suggest watching a DIY repair video so you at least know what's involved no matter who does the fixing.

These types of valves often have rubber seals on the moving part which can wear or even break down over time. The major brands normally have "rebuild kits" which include new replacements for the worn parts. Aside from common tools like screwdriver and pliers, the work may also require a specialty tool to tighten or loosen certain parts.

Your photo shows a one-handle Delta shower/tub faucet and I found a YouTube video showing how to fix it.  I've included some screencaps below, but there are too many details to describe the whole process below -- watch the video!

[How to Repair a Delta Tub / Shower Valve by ramonasplumber](https://youtu.be/SaHUMbUZbHk)

*What's behind the wall*

[image: What's behind the wall]

*Rebuild Kit Parts*

[image]

*Valve Guts Visible*

[image]